# Rebuilding a list with new var values jquery

Tags: jquery, object

Is it possible to recreate an object after it is loaded with a new value passed in by the user?

For example I have an object full of api call information including things like the name and the rest url with required attributes.

```
var masterCallList = [
   {'CallName':'GetMerchantData','CallUrl': '/Merchants/?MerchantId=' + MerchantId + '&ApiKey=' + ApiKey, 'CallType':'Get', 'Desc':''},
   {'CallName':'GetMerchantFeed','CallUrl': '/FeedReturnItems/?MerchantId=' + MerchantId + '&ApiKey=' + ApiKey', 'CallType':'Get' 'Desc':''}
];
```

On page load I loop through each call and build html elements from it including creating onclick events that then run the call.

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    //create the call lists and page elements from the master
    BuildCallLists();
```

My problem is that I want to allow the user to change one of the variables, like merchantid, that they are requesting information on but when they are rebuilt they do not have the new value.

Comment: It would probably be better to construct those values at the time you perform the calls, by getting the user-changeable values from the form, rather than at page load time.

Comment: @Barmar That makes sense however I building html elements at the same time and the editorial staff that I have on hand does not always have access to all of the variables they might need to set. So in this I've done it for them. The need to change is really just for myself and the engineer handling the api so in all reality we could just mod the jquery itself each time. We just would prefer not too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having `CallUrl` as a string, you can make it a function which takes parameters, e.g.:

```
var masterCallList = [
  {'CallName':'GetMerchantData','CallUrlFun': function(MerchantId, ApiKey) { return '/Merchants/?MerchantId=' + MerchantId + '&ApiKey=' + ApiKey; }, 'CallType':'Get', 'Desc':''},
  {'CallName':'GetMerchantFeed','CallUrlFun': function(MerchantId, ApiKey) { return '/FeedReturnItems/?MerchantId=' + MerchantId + '&ApiKey=' + ApiKey; }, 'CallType':'Get', 'Desc':''}
];
```

where `CallUrlFun` is the new function. Now you can call the function instead with the given parameters `(MerchantId, ApiKey)`. Here's a jsFiddle example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/ywVmy/

Another option would be to have a special moniker in the string and to string replaces, such as:

```
var masterCallList = [
  {'CallName':'GetMerchantData','CallUrlTemplate': '/Merchants/?MerchantId=##MerchantId##&ApiKey=##ApiKey##', 'CallType':'Get', 'Desc':''},
  {'CallName':'GetMerchantFeed','CallUrlTemplate': '/FeedReturnItems/?MerchantId=##MerchantId##&ApiKey=##ApiKey##', 'CallType':'Get', 'Desc':''}
];
```

where you have `CallUrlTemplate` containing the monikers `##MerchantId##` and `##ApiKey##`. Here's an example jsFiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/ALbxC/

Incidentally, usually in JavaScript the variable names start with a lower case letter (e.g. merchantId instead of MerchantId).

Comment: Sorry for the lag, just now getting the chance to test this, it makes sense however I'll let you know how it turns out. Also I am aware that generally you would start your variables with lower case, these are just column names I pulled from bd and was too lazy to drop-caps on.

Comment: Thanks, this worked out perfectly. Now the user can set a new variable via a simple input. I was also able to add this to other calls so that the user can create new user accounts, new merchants, and get/put changes to an existing account.